# VBA Macro Code to Auto Fill value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro code where I want the value of column Q to be autofilled based on first value of cell Q2 till last active row based on adjacent column last row (Say column P). The issue is that I do not want starting point to be fixed at Q2, as the row will keep on changing once first auto fill is done.

For example - first I might want to autofill Q2 to Q10, assuming last row as row 10, but then last row will become row 20, and hence I want to copy Q11 to Q20 and so on. Any simple macro to do this?

Any support is highly appreciated.

Thanks
Manis

Comment: Please add code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 'Copy LT
        Workbooks(NameOfFile).Activate
        Range("PQ" & Count & ":PQ" & Count).Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Indata").Activate
        Range("Q" & Lastrow + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

        Dim FillTo As Range
        Set FillTo = Range("P" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1)     'Change 'P' if youhave another active column
        Range(FillTo, FillTo.End(xlUp)).FillDown
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following code:

```
Sub Filldown()
Dim FillTo As Range
    Set FillTo = Range("P" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1)     'Change 'P' if youhave another active column
    Range(FillTo, FillTo.End(xlUp)).Filldown
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Jochen, Thanks for the quick response. but it is still giving me some trouble, i have pasted code below.

Comment: 'Copy LT
            Workbooks(NameOfFile).Activate
            Range("PQ" & Count & ":PQ" & Count).Copy
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Indata").Activate
            Range("Q" & Lastrow + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
            
            Dim FillTo As Range
            Set FillTo = Range("P" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1)     'Change 'P' if youhave another active column
            Range(FillTo, FillTo.End(xlUp)).FillDown

Answer (score -1):

This should help you.

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow1 As Long, lastRow2 As Long
    Dim srcRange As Range, fillRange As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'change to your sheet
    With ws
        lastRow1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp).Row 'last row of Column Q
        lastRow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row 'last row of Column P
        Set srcRange = .Range("Q" & lastRow1)
        Set fillRange = .Range("Q" & lastRow1 & ":q" & lastRow2)
        srcRange.AutoFill Destination:=fillRange
    End With
End Sub
```